# After export NLS_LANG, performance of the shell(query database and export to txt files) very low

Tags: oracle, performance, shell

Version:
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Oracle Database:Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition

NLS_CHARACTERSET: AL32UTF8

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: UTF8

LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Issue: We have a shell to query database and export the data into txt files. In the shell, we use sqlplus to select database , use TRIMSPOOL to export the data into txt files. But there have messy codes issue for some special characters such as ‘®’ in the generated txt files. The special characters is correct in database. But after we use select queries in sqlplus, messy codes returns.

Fix: The NLS_CHARACTERSET in database is AL32UTF8. To resolve the messy codes issue , we added “export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8"” in the shell. **The messy codes issue fixed ,but the runtime is abnormal. it becomes very long , maybe several times longer and cause the shell timeout finally.**

Before we export NLS_LANG, the runtime of the shell is okay. The only difference is whether we add “export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8"” in the shell or not.

I thought when the encoding of database and the client are same, there may have no validation and transformation about the encoding. But seems the result is not like that.

Anyone can help resolve my issue(We are not going to change the encoding of oracle database)? Thanks.

Comment: Is the content of the files still correct, or have all the text columns suddenly got 4 times wider than they were before, and the files are much bigger? It could just be much slower writing the extra bytes to disk, though you might need to be on a slow network share to notice that much. If that is the case then you could add `column` settings to change the behaviour; but maybe try using SQLcl instead of SQL\*Plus and see if that avoids the issue?

Comment: Don't you have also `NLS_SORT` exported? AFAIK sqlplus ignores `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` env. variable unless `NLS_LANG` is exported too. So maybe after you did set `NLS_LANG`, sqlplus started interpreting other env. variables.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your response.  the content of the files is correct after export NLS_LANG.  We did not add new columns. The size of the files did not become bigger. The only difference is that we  export NLS_LANG in the shell.  And the runtime became  n times.

Comment: @ibre5041  Thanks for your response.  we only export NLS_LANG.  we did not export NLS_SORT or NLS_DATE_FORMAT.